# pData Undeclared-Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am getting an error for the below program on the data_derived.m

### data_derived.m

```
@implementation requestSession

- (id)init {
    self=[super initWithID:ID withData:(id)pData withSize:sizeof(st)];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

### data_derived.h

```
@interface requestSession : data {
 //declarations
}
```

### data.h

```
- (id)initWithID:(int) uMessageId withData:(id)pData withSize:(size_t) uDataSize;
```

### data.m

```
- (id) initWithID:(int) uMessageId withData:(id)pData withSize:(size_t) uDataSize {
 //stmts;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, by convention class names start with an uppercase character.

Then, in your `init` there are variables named `ID`, `pData` or `st`. What you probably want to do is either throw an exception here (if the normal `init` is not to be used) or provide default values, as in:

```
[super initWithID:0 withData:nil withSize:0]
```